# DataTable.Select acts diffrent in win7 and winXP

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-xp

This code works great in Win7, 
but in WinXP throws this error: (Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String

```
DataRow[] holrows = HOLIDAY.Select(hol.HOLIDAY.HOLIDAY_DATEColumn.ColumnName + " = ' + CurrDate + "'");
```

To fix it I use String.Format and it works but I don't understand why

```
DataRow[] holrows = HOLIDAY.Select(String.Format(hol.HOLIDAY.HOLIDAY_DATEColumn.ColumnName              + " = '{0}' , CurrDate));
```

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: It's more likely you have different versions of the .net framework on the two pcs, rather than it being the OS itself.

Comment: It is even more likely that this is caused by different regional settings on the two machines, resulting in different date formats when CurrDate is automatically ToString()-ed. Check your regional settings in Windows.

Comment: Forgot to say that when i'm printing the string in the two ways - they turn out the same